# asp classic resetting REQUEST.COOKIES("user")

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, cookies, cross-domain

sorry, I am a very amateur programmer - I am trying to solve a problem with customers placing an order...

....how to reset `REQUEST.COOKIES("user")`

after placing an order the thank you page - using this code

```
Dim pay_status, c_id
pay_status = "yes"`
c_id = REQUEST.COOKIES("user")

Query = "Select * FROM orders WHERE cust_id ='" & c_id & "'"
Set record = Connection.Execute(Query)

c_id = ""
```

if the customer keeps the browser open and places a new order it will add the items from previous order.
I am thinking if I can reset the `REQUEST.COOKIES("user")` it will solve the problem.  using `c_id = ""` did not work.  thanks for any help!

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate cookies use the response object.

To remove the cookie:

```
Response.Cookies("user").Expires = DateAdd("d",-1,Now())
```

To set a new value:

```
Response.Cookies("user") = newval
```

I don’t think it makes sense to change the userid when an order has been placed, but that’s another discussion.